# Stuck in login loop after partial upgrading

Tags: 20.04, login-screen, partial-upgrade

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.

The Software Updater prompted to do a partial upgrade and I proceeded. Then after the reboot I'm stuck on a login loop.

Edit: Update and Upgrade don't work either in the command line interface.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop) This question worked for me, but I had to try a few answers before it worked.

Comment: Login loop or boot loop? They will be very different.